# Parallel mysql queries in php?

Tags: php, mysql, parallel-processing

I am sharding my data into multiple mysql databases, but sometimes I will need to gather information from multiple shards.  How can I query multiple mysql databases in parallel in php?

I've seen some examples of asynchronous curl requests and shell_exec, but is there a more direct way?

Answer (score 4):

The new mysqlnd driver can perform asynchronous queries. Documentation is sparse, but there are some examples (also relating to sharding) in a presentation [here](http://blog.ulf-wendel.de/?p=201).

Comment: Here is a better link I think.  http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2013/03/06/accessing-xtradb-cluster-nodes-in-parallel-from-php-using-mysql-asynchronous-calls/